# Now angularjs elvis is not required?

Tags: angularjs

I was watching a tutorial and learn about Elvis in angularjs. Then I create an object:

```
cabecaDeGelo{
    name: 'jailson',
    lastname: 'mendes',
    address: {
       street: null,
       lol: 'lol'
   }
}
```

And tried

Name: `{{ cabecaDeGelo.name}}` -> works fine

Street: `{{ cabecaDeGelo.address.street }}` -> works fine
WHAT???

`{{ cabecaDeGelo.address.street }}` generate a error 'cause doesn't exist! It is NULL! tutorial show a console error. I was thinking it's a version problem? Now I don't need anymore ELVIS?

like: `{{ cabecaDeGelo.address?.street }}`?
I was confused.

My configuration is`@angular/cli: 1.0.4 / node: 6.10.3`

Comment: did you declared `cabecaDeGelo = {}` with blank object?? please add full component code.. I'm guessing because initially object value defined with `{}` since 1st level `cabecaDeGelo.address` doesn't fail, whereas 2nd level would fail `cabecaDeGelo.address.street` where address is undefined..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Displaying a null or undefined value is not a problem (and has never been, neither in JavaScript, nor in an angular expression).

What is a problem and causes an exception is to display a property of a null or undefined reference.

For example:

```
const foo = {
    bar: null
}
```

Displaying `foo.bar` if not a problem. What is a problem if to display, for example, `foo.bar.baz`, because you can't access a property (`baz`) of a null (or undefined) reference (`foo.bar`). That's where the null-safe navigation operator is needed:

```
{{ foo.bar?.baz }}: OK
{{ foo.bar.baz }}: exception
```

Comment: `{{ foo.bar }}`: show nothing but object is null
`{{ foo.bar?.baz }}`: OK
`{{ foo.bar.baz }}`: exception.
Should be `{{ foo?.bar }}` to show nothing i don't get it yet why return empty and not an error...thx